# SQL Server Connection Error: Configuration system failed to initialize

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am getting this error in my winform when trying to connect to sql server and dont understand why. Here is the error: Configuration system failed to initialize.

Here is my code:

```
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Connect5").ConnectionString

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        myConnection.Open()
```

Here is my app.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
<section name="TestConsoleApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
<source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="FileLog"/>
                <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="FileLog"
             type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
             initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
        <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->

    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Connect5" connectionString="Data Source=asapinc.local\SQLEXPRESSSERVER;Initial Catalog=ASAP_DATABASE; User ID=ASAP;Password=CLEAN1"/>
```

Comment: I doubt this is it, but I noticed you have a space after between the semi-colon and User ID:  `; User ID=` in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like broken config file ..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41cfc8e2-c7f4-462d-9a43-e751500deb0a/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-help-please

Answer (score 0):

You should see a red underline on the word `xml` in this line

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

> Unexpected XML declaration. The XML Declaration must be the first node
>   in the document and **no white space characters** are allowed to appears
>   before it

Comment: Sorry there are no red underline anywhere in the app.config file

Comment: But do you have a space before the first line?